# Is it possible to install an msi using python?

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to write a script in python that installs an msi? Or 
is it possible to make it through any other script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the antiquated [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system)`('msiexec /i whatever.msi')`, or, better, the `subprocess` equivalent [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess.call#subprocess.call) -- in either case, you can also add whatever further `msiexec` flags or arguments you desire (documentation in abundance [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true)).

Comment: Oh noes alex!  Don't be suggesting someone use `os.system`!  Seriously, go to `subprocess`, please.

Comment: @Nick & @Alex
Thank you and is there any notable difference between using  os.system and subprocess?

Comment: @The Learner: `os.system` is a fire-and-forget solution to running another process in a subshell.  However, you can't control it in any way, you can't get access to its' `stdout/stderr`, you can't control the shell used on windows, and `subprocess` provides a lot of additional functionality that is very useful for process communication and management.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it's possible to use WMI in Python, so you should be able to install MSI files using the [`Win32_Product.Install`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390890.aspx) method.

Comment: im a complete newbie in scripting..
so, what way should i prefer? os.system/subprocess or the WMI ?
pls advice
thanks..

Comment: @The Learner: I have no idea; I don't know Python myself (unfortunately). But in VBScript and PowerShell scripting, WMI is pretty handy for this kind of task.