# How to execute MSI installer from python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, windows-installer, os.system

I need to install node.js from my python script.
I tried these solutions:

[Is it possible to install an msi using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130252/is-it-possible-to-install-an-msi-using-python)

[install .rpm or .msi file through python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484772/install-rpm-or-msi-file-through-python-script)

I tried with these various code:

```
os.system('msiexec /i %s /qn' % 'node_install.msi')
subprocess.check_call(["msiexec /i node_install.msi"])
subprocess.Popen('node_install.msi')
```

But I get the error message:

```
[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Here is my script which downloads successfully the MSI file:

```
if platform.architecture()[0] == "64bit":
    wget.download('https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.15.0/node-v12.15.0-x64.msi','node_install.msi')
    logger.info("We will try now to install NodeJS 64Bits. Please follow the installation process.")
    #os.system('msiexec /i %s /qn' % 'node_install.msi')
    #subprocess.check_call(["msiexec /i node_install.msi"])
    subprocess.Popen('node_install.msi')
else:
    wget.download('https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.15.0/node-v12.15.0-x86.msi', 'node_install.msi')
    logger.info("We will try now to install NodeJS 32Bits. Please follow the installation process.")
    #os.system('msiexec /i %s /qn' % 'node_install.msi')
    #subprocess.check_call(["msiexec /i node_install.msi"])
    subprocess.Popen('node_install.msi')
```

Does anyone already succeed in installing an MSI from a python script?

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_call` accepts a kind of vector, so you should call it this way: `subprocess.check_call(["msiexec", "/i", "node_install.msi"])`